# How do I scrape data from a .aspx website Using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from http://corp.sec.state.ma.us/CorpWeb/CorpSearch/CorpSearchResults.aspx
I want to open every on the page, so that I can scrape the company data.
From each company's page, I want to scrape; The exact name of the Domestic Profit Corporation, 
Entity type, Identification Number, Date of Organization in Massachusetts, Date of Involuntary,The location of the Principal Office, The name and address of the Registered Agent and The Officers and Directors of the Corporation. After I have scraped data from all companies on the first page, I want to click the next page at the bottom to go to page 2 and repeat the same process.
So far, I have been able to open the website with selenium, and search all companies that begin with L, i have also opened the next page but I can't figure out how to scrape data from the company tables. I want to scrape data from each company and save it in a csv.
Here is my code so far;

```
import requests, os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import string 

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

#Site url
url = 'http://corp.sec.state.ma.us/corpweb/CorpSearch/CorpSearch.aspx' #starting url
browser.get(url)
userElem = browser.find_element_by_id('MainContent_txtEntityName')
# Looping through all the characters in the alphabet plus numbers 0 - 9
for i in string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits[1:]:
    print(i)
userElem.send_keys('l')
linkEleme = browser.find_element_by_id('MainContent_btnSearch')
linkEleme.click()
time.sleep(20)
p = browser.current_url
print('This is the new url: ',(p))

#TODO: Find the href link to each corporation on the page
url2 = p
browser.get(p)
business_elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('link')
j = browser.find_element_by_id('MainContent_SearchControl_grdSearchResultsEntity')
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in j.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]

#Finding all the links on the first page 
# Find all the links on the page
linkList = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
correct_links = []
for i in range(len(linkList)):
    f = (linkList[i]).get_attribute('href')
    if f.startswith('http://corp.sec.state.ma.us'):
        correct_links.append(f)
print(len(correct_links))

print('Collecting links on the next pages.....')
for i in range(2, 27):
    try:
        x_path_element = '//*[@id="MainContent_SearchControl_grdSearchResultsEntity"]/tbody/tr[27]/td/table/tbody/tr/' + 'td' + '['+ str(i) + ']'+ '/a'
        print('Going to the page {}.....'.format(i))
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(str(x_path_element)).click()
        time.sleep(20)
        r = browser.current_url
        print('This is the new url: ',(r))
        #'//*[@id="MainContent_SearchControl_grdSearchResultsEntity"]/tbody/tr[27]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a'
        print('Finding links on the page {}.....'.format(r))
        linkList2 = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        for i in range(len(linkList2)):
            f = (linkList2[i]).get_attribute('href')
            if f.startswith('http://corp.sec.state.ma.us'):
                correct_links.append(f)
        for i in correct_links:
            # Opening the links that we found in correct_links
            print(i)
    except:
        print('The link is for page {} is dead'.format(i))
print(len((correct_links)))
print('Finding the data about the companies')

print('Preparing a csv file to store data')
with open('Mass_company_data.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("ID Number, Company Name, Entity Type, Date of Organization in Mass, Address, City, Owner, Owner Address \n")



for i in correct_links:
    # Opening the links that we found in correct_links
    print(i)
    browser.get(i)
    # scrape new page data
    j = browser.current_url
    company_data  = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('p1')
```

**Update:**
I have been able to scroll through the page and find all the companies on all the pages but I still can't figure out how to scrape data from each company's page

Comment: Just loop from 2 to the last page and click those links (you'll have to click '...' once in a while). For the details pages you can use something faster like requests or scrapy.